# How to place components on two ends of a modal in React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to place my two components one being a switch toggle and a button at the two ends of a modal. I am able to place them using a flexbox. The current result is as shown in the image. I want the button to be placed in the right end of the modal. What styling should I include in my `.scss` file. I am working in React JS.

Comment: Have you researched how flex-box works? I think you'd find the answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using flexbox, `justify-content: space-between` is probably what you're looking for.
Here's [a great guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on what you can achieve using flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content: space-between` in wrapper which contains these inputs.

This adds equal gaps between all elements, so both will be at the edges.